# Bottomsheet disappear when view is updated

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a bottomsheet, where when a view is clicked, the user can select a date from a calendar modal. When the user select the date, a MutableLiveData is updated. In the fragment, there is the observer of the LiveData, but when I want to update the text on the bottomsheet with the date selected, the bottomsheet disappears (even if the state if still EXPANDED, and if i try to show the bottomsheet it does not appear).

Fragment

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentViability2Binding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        destinationBottomSheetBinding = FragmentViabilityBottomSheetV2Binding.bind(binding.root)
        return binding.root
    }
```

```
destinationBottomSheetBinding.apply {
            val behavior: BottomSheetBehavior<*> = BottomSheetBehavior.from(mywayBottomSheet)
            behavior.isHideable = false
            behavior.isDraggable = true
            behavior.peekHeight = 0
            behavior.skipCollapsed = true

            behavior.addBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
                override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                    Timber.w(newState.toString())

                    if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED || newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                        viabilityViewModel.destinationDate.value = null
                    }
                }

                override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
                }

            })

            closePlace.setOnClickListener {
                collapsePlaceBottomSheet()
            }
        }
```

```
        viabilityViewModel.destinationDate.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            if (it != null) {
                destinationBottomSheetBinding.tripPlannerTimeLabel.text =
                    SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMMM - HH:mm", Locale.ITALY).format(it)

                binding.searchFullScreen.tripPlannerTimeLabel.text =
                    SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMMM - HH:mm", Locale.ITALY).format(it)
            } else {
                destinationBottomSheetBinding.tripPlannerTimeLabel.text = getString(R.string.viability_trip_planner_now)
                binding.searchFullScreen.tripPlannerTimeLabel.text = getString(R.string.viability_trip_planner_now)
            }
        }
```

Comment: As per the snippet, It seems like you are making a mistake in the onCreateView method.

Comment: @Bhavnik why do you say that? I'm just binding the view